# Django not submitting and updating form data

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to figure out why Django is not submitting form data to update the user profile. Profile.html should be reflecting the newly updated input data (i.e., first_name, last_name) from Edit-profile.html.

forms.py

```
class EditUserProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, required=False)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=150, required=False)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    state = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=False)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)
    credit_card_number = forms.CharField(max_length=16, required=False)
    expiration_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    cvv = forms.CharField(max_length=3, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code',
                  'username', 'password', 'credit_card_number', 'expiration_date', 'cvv']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(EditUserProfile, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        user.state = self.cleaned_data['state']
        user.zip_code = self.cleaned_data['zip_code']
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        user.credit_card_number = self.cleaned_data['credit_card_number']
        user.expiration_date = self.cleaned_data['expiration_date']
        user.cvv = self.cleaned_data['cvv']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_profile_page(request):
    form = EditUserProfile(initial={
        'first_name': request.user.first_name if hasattr(request.user, 'first_name') else '',
        'last_name': request.user.last_name if hasattr(request.user, 'last_name') else '',
        'phone_number': request.user.phone_number if hasattr(request.user, 'phone_number') else '',
        'email': request.user.email if hasattr(request.user, 'email') else '',
        'address': request.user.address if hasattr(request.user, 'address') else '',
        'city': request.user.city if hasattr(request.user, 'city') else '',
        'state': request.user.state if hasattr(request.user, 'state') else '',
        'zip_code': request.user.zip_code if hasattr(request.user, 'zip_code') else '',
        'username': request.user.username if hasattr(request.user, 'username') else '',
        'password': request.user.password if hasattr(request.user, 'password') else '',
        'credit_card_number': request.user.credit_card_number if hasattr(request.user, 'credit_card_number') else '',
        'expiration_date': request.user.expiration_date if hasattr(request.user, 'expiration_date') else '',
        'cvv': request.user.cvv if hasattr(request.user, 'cvv') else '',
    })

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditUserProfile(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            request.user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            request.user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            request.user.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            request.user.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
            request.user.zip_code = form.cleaned_data['zip_code']
            request.user.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            request.user.password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            request.user.credit_card_number = form.cleaned_data['credit_card_number']
            request.user.expiration_date = form.cleaned_data['expiration_date']
            request.user.cvv = form.cleaned_data['cvv']
            request.user.save()
            return redirect('edit_profile_page')

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile/edit-profile.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from .views import (
    profile_page,
    login_page,
    logout_page,
    register_page,
    edit_profile_page,

)

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', login_page, name='login'),
    path('logout/', logout_page, name='logout'),
    path('profile/', profile_page, name='profile'),
    path('edit-profile/', edit_profile_page, name='edit-profile'),
    path('register/', register_page, name='register')
]
```

edit-profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %} <main class="d-xxl-flex align-items-xxl-center" style="background: linear-gradient(#3B8BEB 20%, var(--bs-gray-100) 88%, #E7E3D4 100%), linear-gradient(#3B8BEB 20%, var(--bs-gray-100) 88%, #E7E3D4 100%), linear-gradient(#3B8BEB 20%, var(--bs-gray-100) 88%, #E7E3D4 100%), var(--bs-white);height: 100%;">
  <div class="container" style="padding: 30px;">
    <div class="main-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                <img class="rounded-circle bg-primary p-1" src="{% static 'img/LuluMW_Logo.png' %}" alt="Admin" width="110">
                <div class="mt-3">
                  <h4>Name</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %} <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">First Name</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{ user.first_name }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Last Name</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{{ user.last_name }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Phone Number</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_number" value="{{ user.phone_number }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Email</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ user.email }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Address</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">City</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" value="{{ user.city }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">State</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" value="{{ user.state }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Zip</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip_code" value="{{ user.zip_code }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Username</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ user.username }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Password</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ user.password }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Credit Card Number</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="credit_card_number" value="{{ user.credit_card_number }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Expiration Date</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="expiration_date" value="{{ user.expiration_date }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">CVV</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cvv" value="{{ user.cvv }}">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4">Save Changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</main> {% endblock content %}
```

profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %} <main class="d-xxl-flex align-items-xxl-center" style="background: linear-gradient(#3B8BEB 20%, var(--bs-gray-100) 88%, #E7E3D4 100%), linear-gradient(#3B8BEB 20%, var(--bs-gray-100) 88%, #E7E3D4 100%), linear-gradient(#3B8BEB 20%, var(--bs-gray-100) 88%, #E7E3D4 100%), var(--bs-white);height: 100%;">
  <div class="container" style="padding: 30px;">
    <div class="main-body">
      <form method="post"> {% csrf_token %} <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                  <img class="rounded-circle bg-primary p-1" src="{% static 'img/LuluMW_Logo.png' %}" alt="Admin" width="110">
                  <div class="mt-3">
                    <h4>Name</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">First Name</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">{{ user.first_name }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Last Name</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">{{ user.last_name }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Phone Number</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">{{ user.phone_number }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Email</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Address</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">{{ user.address }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">City</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">{{ user.city }}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">State</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    {{ user.state }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Zip</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    {{ user.zip_code }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Username</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    {{ user.username }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Password</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Credit Card Number</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    {{ user.credit_card_number }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">Expiration Date</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    {{ user.expiration_date }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <h6 class="mb-0">CVV</h6>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 text-secondary">
                    {{ user.cvv }}
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <hr>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12"><a class="btn btn-info" role="button" target="__blank" href="/accounts/edit-profile/">Edit</a></div>
                  </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Everything possible.

Comment: Why you don't want to use [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)